# defining replicas in docker-compose as integer variables

Tags: docker-compose, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

VSTS release fails with an error for using an integer variable for docker replicas.

I want to define different replicas values in different environment in azure vsts release pipelines.
I have docker-compose with following setting.
`replicas: ${REPLICAS}`

REPLICAS is defined as vsts build(set to 1) and release variable(set to 1 for dev , qa and 3 for prod).

The build is success and release returns error stating

### [error]services.serviceName.deploy.replicas must be a integer

Successful release is expected result.

Comment: What is meaning of the qa and 3 for prod? Did it mean that your REPLICAS variable value is qa and 3? According to your error message, replicas must be a integer but seems like there is string in your release variable.

Comment: replica is set to 1 for dev and qa and 3 for prod so that we have 1 container in lower env and 3 in prod. It seems this is a know limitation of Azure VSTS where they don't allow integer values as pipeline variables. I found a workaround this. The solution is to create a  docker task in release pipeline for prod that run docker service scale command after deployment. i.e service update --replicas=$(REPLICA) $(SERVICE) .  This command in vsts stage task can accept string value of replica.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolve this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Comment: I can't mark as I don't have reputation yet, I guess can only mark after I earn 50.

Answer (score 0):

Integer value can not be defined for a vsts release variable. The work around solution is to create a docker service scale task in prod stage to scale service to 3 or more containers.This is defined just after the docker service deploy task in release pipeline . This task will run docker service scale command after service deployment. Here is the command specified -> `service update --replicas=$(REPLICA) $(SERVICENAME)` . This command in vsts stage task can accept string value of REPLICA . REPLICA and SERVICENAME are both vsts release variables.